# How to assign multiple "each" values within function rep()?

Tags: r, function, repeat

I know I've accomplished this before, but I'm just not figuring it out again! Here's the vector I want to produce with the `rep()` function:

```
> myvec    
> A1   A1   B1   B1   B1   B1
```

I know how to use `each` to produce A1 and B1 the same number of times: `rep(c("A1", "B1"), each = 2)`. But how do I specify different values for `each` to repeat A1 twice and B1 three times?

Comment: Don't use `each=` - `rep(c("A1", "B1"),c(2,3))`

Comment: Use the `times` argument instead of `each` (which, given the above comment, appears to be the second argument to the function)

Comment: If my answer was helpful please upvote and accept, this is how this community works... Thank you!

Comment: @user8121557 could you please accept the answer given by `@vonjd?

Answer (score 7):

Although it is a little counterintuitive the following works:

```
> rep(c("A1", "B1"), times = c(2, 3))
[1] "A1" "A1" "B1" "B1" "B1"
```